# A big unicorn hug

Tags: discussion, unicorns, appreciation

### Thanks everyone – April 1st was awesome.

I appreciate you all defending my fragile creatures against evil spoil-sports and devilish rainbow-haters.

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/5100/requestl.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/5100/requestl.png)

Comment: Please leave this up for a while before cleaning it up with the rest of the unicorn questions. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm so glad there is no rainbow in this picture. (And go...)

Comment: It was awesome.  But would it have been awesomer with jQuery?  I'm an embedded programmer, I don't even know what jQuery is.

Comment: That's an awesome way to show your traffic graph! Thank you for the gift of corny you'n's!

Comment: just curious, what do you use to generate that graph? is it provided by GAE? pretty nice resolution.

Comment: @matt b: Yes, the GAE gives you that graph; up to 24h. The picture is combined from two screenshots.

Answer (score 10):

Use caution when hugging your unicorn.

[alt text http://whatnottocrochet.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/unicorn.jpg](http://whatnottocrochet.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/unicorn.jpg)

Comment: That would have been better if it was piercing Balpha's avatar or unicorn...

Comment: @Chester - I dug up a picture of a unicorn murdering a teddy bear, but that's apparently not good enough for you. The nerve of some people!

Comment: I upvoted this post long ago!

Answer (score 6):

Good work @balpha and cheers to the management for actually doing this!!!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reminding me to upload my unicorn to gravatar. :) I intend on keeping mine and have named it `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

Fine, except you awakened me to the harsh and, frankly, terrifying world of cute unicorns. I rely on my avatar (夢, which means "dream") to keep me calm and trancelike in the zone. A Xanax helped, but how can I ever trust SO again?

"Was it a vision, or a waking dream? Fled is that music:—do I wake or sleep?"

Answer (score 0):

It was :) Thanks for your contribution!